# Convert date string to NSDate?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I convert `Sep 15, 2015, 20:49:00` to `2015-09-15T20:49:00` using Swift? I'm fetching a `date` object from Parse but need to convert it to a different format.

EDIT AFTER BEING MARKED DUPLICATE:

I'm using this :

```
let time = "Sat Sep 19 2015 19:03:47 GMT+0000 (UTC)"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSS'Z'"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(listenTime)
```

...and getting `nil`. So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try like this: .dateFormat = "EEE' 'LLL' 'dd' 'yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss' GMT+0000 (UTC)'" You will need to specify also the calendar NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601, the timeZone "GMT" and the locale "en_US_POSIX"

Comment: Can you please post an answer? I'm getting the wrong hour. Must be a time zone issue.

Comment: You are inputing UTC the hour it is probably your local time corresponding to the UTC time inputed

Comment: Ok so I don't want to change the time, just the format. How do I keep the time consistent?

Comment: Just make sure the input is always GMT (UTC)

Comment: I'm doing `let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                                                            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE' 'LLL' 'dd' 'yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss' GMT+0000 (UTC)'"

                                                            let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(time)` and getting the wrong hour. I don't want to change the hour.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32706994/2303865

Comment: Reopened because the selected duplicate was not at all a duplicate.

Comment: @dperk To convert a date string from one format to another you need two formats. One that matches the original string so you can convert the original string to an NSDate, and the second format to covert the NSDate to the new format.

Answer (score 1):

```
let time = "Sat Sep 19 2015 19:03:47 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
let df = NSDateFormatter()
df.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601)
df.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
df.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
df.dateFormat = "EEE LLL dd yyyy HH:mm:ss' GMT+0000 (UTC)'"
if let date = df.dateFromString(time) {
    df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    let stringFromDate = df.stringFromDate(date)   // "2015-09-19T19:03:47"
}
```

Comment: There is no need to quote spaces in the date format. Only letters that should be treated as literals.

Comment: I usually I don't but at the end of the string it is necessary to ignore the gmt suffix that I didn't find the corresponding letter for that specific format

Comment: I meant just do: `"EEE LLL dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT+0000 (UTC)'"`

Comment: Thats what I said only the sufix needs to be ignored

Comment: Right. Then why escape all the other spaces?

Comment: @rmaddy I tried it because all letters that I have tried wasn't working to identify the time zone